# Eclipse won't launch Minecraft

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

What do I do? My minecraft won't launch through eclipse! Here is the crash report:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----


Time: 2/16/17 9:43 AM
Description: Initializing game

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.item.crafting.CraftingManager.addRecipe(CraftingManager.java:266)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry.addShapedRecipe(GameRegistry.java:236)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry.addRecipe(GameRegistry.java:231)
    at com.student.emod.EMod.init(EMod.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLModContainer.handleModStateEvent(FMLModContainer.java:518)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:208)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:187)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:118)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Loader.initializeMods(Loader.java:692)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.finishMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:291)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.startGame(Minecraft.java:521)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:356)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(Unknown Source)
    at GradleStart.main(Unknown Source)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.item.crafting.CraftingManager.addRecipe(CraftingManager.java:266)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry.addShapedRecipe(GameRegistry.java:236)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry.addRecipe(GameRegistry.java:231)
    at com.student.emod.EMod.init(EMod.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLModContainer.handleModStateEvent(FMLModContainer.java:518)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:208)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:187)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:118)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Loader.initializeMods(Loader.java:692)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.finishMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:291)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.startGame(Minecraft.java:521)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:356)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(Unknown Source)
    at GradleStart.main(Unknown Source)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.8
    Operating System: Windows 8 (amd64) version 6.2
    Java Version: 1.7.0_51, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 846509440 bytes (807 MB) / 1038876672 bytes (990 MB) up to 1038876672 bytes (990 MB)
    JVM Flags: 3 total; -Xincgc -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: MCP v9.10 FML v8.0.37.1334 Minecraft Forge 11.14.1.1334 5 mods loaded, 5 mods active
    mcp{9.05} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    FML{8.0.37.1334} [Forge Mod Loader] (forgeSrc-1.8-11.14.1.1334.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    Forge{11.14.1.1334} [Minecraft Forge] (forgeSrc-1.8-11.14.1.1334.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    examplemod{1.0} [Example Mod] (bin) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    emod{1.0} [emod] (bin) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Errored
    Loaded coremods (and transformers): 
    Launched Version: 1.8
    LWJGL: 2.9.1
    OpenGL: Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 GL version 4.4.0 - Build 20.19.15.4549, Intel
    GL Caps: Using GL 1.3 multitexturing.
Using GL 1.3 texture combiners.
Using framebuffer objects because OpenGL 3.0 is supported and separate blending is supported.
Shaders are available because OpenGL 2.1 is supported.
VBOs are available because OpenGL 1.5 is supported.

    Using VBOs: No
    Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fml,forge'
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: []
    Current Language: English (US)
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
```

I am pretty sure my mod I am trying to make is not a fault. I even tried launching without the mod. It still didn't work. Anyway, Here's my mod code:

```
package com.student.emod;

import net.minecraft.init.Blocks;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraft.enchantment.Enchantment;
import net.minecraft.init.Items;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraftforge.common.ChestGenHooks;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;

@Mod(modid = EMod.MODID, version = EMod.VERSION)
public class EMod
{
    public static final String MODID = "emod";
    public static final String VERSION = "1.0";

    @EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event)
    {
        GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(Items.apple),
                "XXX",
                "XXX",
                "XXX", 
                'X', Blocks.leaves);
        GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(Items.arrow),
                "YZ",
                "X",
                'X', Items.flint, 'Y', Items.stick, 'Z', Blocks.leaves);

        GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(Blocks.end_portal_frame),
                "E",
                "OOO",
                "SSS",
                'E', Items.ender_eye,'O', Blocks.obsidian,'S', Blocks.sand);

        GameRegistry.addShapelessRecipe(new ItemStack(Blocks.obsidian), 
                Items.lava_bucket, 
                Items.water_bucket);
    GameRegistry.addSmelting(Blocks.stone, new ItemStack(Items.lava_bucket, 1), 0.8F);

    }
}
```

Comment: From the stack trace it looks like `com.student.elliotmod.ElliotMod` is the problem. Is that your code?

Comment: I just deleted elliotmod. Minecraft STILL will not launch. The crash report is the same as above but without elliotmod

Comment: The updated stack trace is now pointing at line 32 in `com.student.emod.EMod` - something wrong with the `GameRegistry.addRecipe` call

Comment: how do I fix It

Comment: Sorry, no idea, I don't know the Minecraft APIs. Hopefully someone who does know will be see this.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a long shot, but do you have NVidia Geforce Experience? One of the most recent updates to the NVidia Drivers (update 378.49) conflicts with Java, and so programs/games using Java haven't been responding well, including Minecraft. I know the update 376.66 works just fine, I had to rollback my installation to use Java related products.

Comment: I do not have NVida Geforce. What else might be the problem?